# UIButton Animation issue - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to work on a UIButton animation where the button moves to a point and then is set hidden to be true. However when I tried working on the following code, the button disappeared even before the animation was completed. Am I doing it correctly? Any suggestions?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                 animations:^{

                     selectedCurveIndex = 0;
                     [tradebutton moveTo:
                      CGPointMake(51,150) duration:0.8 
                                  option:curveValues[UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut]];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 

                     [tradeButton setHidden:TRUE];

                     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                     UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ButtonView"];

                     self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                     [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];

                 }];
```

Comment: You need to show us the source for `moveTo:duration:option:`, because that is not a standard UIKit message.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes

Comment: I found it inside the UIView + Animation class

Comment: You need to delay the [tradeButton setHidden:YES] - at least 0.01 second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a second, inner animation  block in the `moveTo:duration:option:` method, and you set all of the animatable properties in that inner block.  You don't set any animatable properties in the outer block.

That means that the system immediately thinks that the outer animation has finished, and calls the completion block right away.  Meanwhile, the inner animation block is still going.

Stop using `moveTo:duration:option:`.  It saves you almost nothing, and ends up giving you trouble like this.  Throw it out and try something like this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
    tradeButton.frame = (CGRect){ CGPointMake(51, 150), tradeButton.bounds.size };
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    tradeButton.hidden = YES;
    // etc.
}];
```

Note that `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInEaseOut` is the default for most animations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that **finished** is set to **YES** before moving on.

Your button hides quickly because **0.8** is a quick animation duration. You will need to figure out another place to hide the button, or you can

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                 animations:^{

                     selectedCurveIndex = 0;
                     [tradebutton moveTo:
                      CGPointMake(51,150) duration:0.8 
                                  option:curveValues[UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut]];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 

                     if ( finished ) 
                     {    
                         [tradeButton performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@"YES" afterDelay:3.0];

                         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                         UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ButtonView"];

                         self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                         [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. the button disappears once i start animation.

Comment: The reason your button is disappearing so fast is because it 0.8 is pretty quick. Change your animation duration to something slower. Other than that, you would need to go about another way of hiding the button rather than when this animation sequence completes.

Comment: Actually, I see another way you can do this I will update my answer.

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan try the updated method of **performSelector:**.

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan Your error happened because `setHidden:` requires a `BOOL` parameter, but `performSelector:withObject:` can only accept an object parameter.  You shouldn't use the `setHidden:` selector with `performSelector:withObject:`.

Comment: Actually, @robmayoff you **can** use **`setHidden:`** with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. You can simply pass @"YES" as the object. I've tested this just now and it works.

Comment: It breaks type safety.  That's why I say you *shouldn't* use it.

Comment: `withObject` of `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay` accepts an id parameter. `YES` is a typedef signed char, hence, it is throwing an error at that point. You might want to change the value being accepted by `setHidden` to id or an NSNumber and convert the argument to BOOL within the method by calling boolValue of NSNumber. You may pass this as an argument: `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` then convert it to BOOL by calling `[setHiddenArg boolValue]` within  your setHidden method.